# How to fill an ArrayList with reading txt file

Tags: java, arraylist, txt

I am working on my code, but I'm trying to fill and ArrayList with whatever one txt file has inside, but it seems like my code do not work and I do not why, I am stuck here, Here is mi code.

```
ArrayList<String> codonList = new ArrayList();
String currentCodonString;

int countProtein = 0;
ArrayList<ProteinSequence> proteinSequences = new ArrayList();

//Here we can add each nucleotide in group of three from the text, and add an array
public void addNucleotide(String nuceotide) {
    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testSequenceOutput.txt"));
        String currentCodonString ="";
        while(read.readLine() != null); {
            codonList.add(currentCodonString);}
    }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
//Here we are going to analyze an array(sequence) and see how much protein
//we are going to found in this array
public int findAllProteinSequences() {
    if(codonList.contains("AUG")) {
        countProtein++;}
    else if(codonList.contains("GUG")) {
        countProtein++; }
    else if(codonList.contains("UGG")) {
        countProtein++;
    }
    else if(codonList.contains("UAA")) {
        countProtein++;
    }
    else if(codonList.contains("UAG")) {
        countProtein++;
    }
    else if(codonList.contains("UGA")) {
        countProtein++;
    }
    return countProtein;
    }
```

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon here : `while(read.readLine() != null);{...}`, with the semi-colon in the while loop never gets to `codonList.add(currentCodonString);`.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like my code do not work and I do not why, I am stuck here

> `}catch(Exception ex) {}`

Well, yes. That's what happens when you catch all exceptions and completly ignore them.

Remove that line. `main` can (and should) be declared to `throws Exception`, and your file reading methods should be declared to `throws IOException`, and then whatever is not working out will become visible.

Note that you're leaking resources here by not closing the buffered reader. You can't just call .close() (what if an exception happens?), search the web for 'java automatic resource management' to learn how to do it. Or just use the new java.nio.file Files API which can read a file into a list of lines with one method call.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

### Squashing exceptions

You should never do this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {}
```

It says *"catch every possible exception and don't say or do anything"*.  In this case, any possible exception includes the `FileNotFoundException` that

```
new FileReader("testSequenceOutput.txt")
```

will throw if it cannot find the file.  But it could also include unexpected things such as a (hypothetical) `NullPointerException` that might be due to something like
`codonList` being `null`.

This is almost as bad:

```
catch (IOException ex) {}
```

It doesn't squash *all* exceptions, but it still going to squash the `FileNotFoundException` or other IO exceptions that might be thrown while opening or reading the file.  You *probably* should tell the user (or the programmer) that the file can't be found ... or whatever.

A better way to deal with this is to change the signature of `addNucleotide` to this:

```
public void addNucleotide(String nuceotide) throws IOException {
    ...
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
              new FileReader("testSequenceOutput.txt"));
    // process file
}
```

Then further up the call stack you should *catch* the `IOException` and do something about it.  Depending on the context, you could print a user-friendly error message or print a stacktrace.  Then you could exit the application or try to take some recovery action; e.g. ask the user for a different filename.

If you really don't want to be bothered with handling the exception, you *could* declare `main` as `throws Exception` or `throws IOException`  But that will lead to the user of your program seeing a stack trace if the file is missing ... or not in the place you expect it to be.  That is ugly, and in the real world you would get bug reports for that.

So someone saying that you **should** declare `main` as `throws Exception` is (IMO) patently bad advice:

- If you handed that in for assessment in an assignment, you should *expect* to lose marks for that.
- If your colleagues code reviewed your code, you should *expect* to get -1 votes on your check-ins for that.
- If you published your code, you should *expect* to get negative comments about that.

### Spurious semicolon

This is what you code says:

```
    String currentCodonString = "";
    while (read.readLine() != null); {
        codonList.add(currentCodonString);
    }
```

Notice the `;` on the second line?

That is an *empty statement*.  What is means is that the *body* of the loop is ... nothing.  So what that code *really* means is this:

```
   String currentCodonString = "";
   while (read.readLine() != null) {
        // do nothing
   }
   codonList.add(currentCodonString);
```

In short you are reading the file and discarding its contents, then adding a single empty string to `codonList`.

### Discarding the lines read

Lets fix the spurious semicolon:

```
   String currentCodonString = "";
   while (read.readLine() != null) {
       codonList.add(currentCodonString);
   }
```

Is that correct?  Nope!

The `(read.readLine() != null)` is reading a line and testing if it is `null`.  But what does it *do with the line* it has just?  It throws it away!  You will end up with `codonList` containing lots of empty strings.

So what you probably need to do is this:

```
   String currentCodonString = read.readLine();
   while (currentCodonString != null) {
       codonList.add(currentCodonString);
       currentCodonString = read.readLine();
   }
```

This *could* be rewritten as this:

```
   String currentCodonString;
   while ((currentCodonString = read.readLine()) != null) {
       codonList.add(currentCodonString);
   }
```

This is a common idiom ... but since there is an assignment expression in the `while` condition, it is not entirely obvious what is happening here.  (Don't do this unless you *understand* it!)

### Resource leakage

The final problem is that you code (potentially) leaks resource descriptors.  When the `addNucleotide(...)` returns ... or terminates due to an exception, it is not closing the file that it opened.

If you do this too often, your application is going to run out of "file descriptors" ... and then other attempts to open files, etc will fail.

You *could* just call `read.close()`, but that doesn't deal with the case where the method exits due to an arbitrary exception.

You *could* use `try { ... } finally { read.close() }` but it is cumbersome and has some awkward edge cases.

The recommended solution to this is:

```
public void addNucleotide(String nuceotide) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
                  new FileReader("testSequenceOutput.txt"))) {
        // process file
        ...
    }
}
```

This is making use of Java 7+ *try with resources* syntax.  The resource in this case is the `BufferedReader` instance in `read`.  When the `try` terminates (normally or with an exception), `read` will be checked.  If it is non-null, it will be closed automatically, and any exceptions resulting from the `close()` will be dealt with *appropriately*.